# Seating arrangements combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking at the following question

> Carla is having a dinner party and is inviting 5 guests: 3 boys and 2
> girls. Carla knows that she needs to sit at the head of the table, but
> hasn't decided on fixed seats for anyone else. If she decides not to
> sit any of her guests next to anyone else of the same gender, how many
> different seating arrangements are possible?

The answer says this:

> This is a tricky seating arrangement question, so think about it
> systematically. If Carla is seated at the head of the table, and no
> two people of the same gender may sit next to each other then our
> seating arrangement must look something like this:

[image]

> Now let's work our way around the table and figure out how many
> different arrangements are possible. Moving clockwise around the
> table, we know that seat 1 must be occupied by a boy, and there are 3
> different boys who could fill this spot. Seat 2 must then be a girl.
> There are 2 different girls who could fill this spot. Seat 3 is
> another boy. Now that one of the boys is seated (next to Carla), only
> 2 boys remain for this seat. Seat 4 is a girl, and only one girl
> remains to sit here. Finally, only one boy remains for seat 5 next to
> Carla. To find the answer, multiply these possibilities. There are 3 x
> 2 x 2 x 1 x 1 = 12 possible seating arrangements.

Isn't it incorrect because it only accounts for one possible arrangement?

I believe another valid arrangement would be

```
  5  4

C ----------
  ---------  
   1  2   3
```

In which case the answer should be 12 * 2 = 24.

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: I think for this problem they don't consider the actual spacial positions of the chairs as important, only the relative positions around the table. The alternative arrangement you give is considered the same under those rules.

Comment: I think in the original version the table was round.

Comment: @StephenDonovan is it just me or is restricting a differential spatial position from counting as an arrangement weird?

Comment: @user Is there a "head of the table" for a round table?

Comment: @nz_21 I think that's a matter of opinion, personally I think it makes sense to consider them the same here because the setups are symmetrical and I don't see why we should treat one side of the table differently from the other.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I don't know what was the reason to introduce "a head of the table" in this problem. I also doubt that a table can have a head, but English is not my native language. :)

Comment: @StephenDonovan left is not the same as right :) I would imagine someone seated to your left is a different arrangement than someone seated to your right...

Comment: Why don't you consider the arrangment where all 5 guests sit on the same side of the table? In this way you will find much more than 24  arrangements. Imagine now that the table has 20 sides and up to 5 people can seat at each side... This will be interesting.